# Shopware index problems

Tags: kernel, shopware, shopware6

we get this error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://www.schuh-bamberg.de/Gabor-Fashion-Plateau-Pumps-91.270.72-Beige-41787"" at /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/releases/20220113161245/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 135 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET https://www.schuh-bamberg.de/Gabor-Fashion-Plateau-Pumps-91.270.72-Beige-41787\" at /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/releases/20220113161245/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:135)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/Gabor-Fashion-Plateau-Pumps-91.270.72-Beige-41787/\". at /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/releases/20220113161245/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:74)"} []
```

What is the problem or what is going wrong?

We tried to restart the indexer but it always comes the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple:
someone (bots, users, ...) called https://www.schuh-bamberg.de/Gabor-Fashion-Plateau-Pumps-91.270.72-Beige-41787

But this page doesn't exist in your shop.
Someone could also call https://www.schuh-bamberg.de/ThisDoesNotExist, and you would see the error in your logs.

Are you really sure any existing product would fit the path by your configurated seo-url-template?